# Estoy usando FPDF, cuando genero la consulta me crea una tabla por cada producto incuso usando un while

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Estoy usando *FPDF*, cuando genero la consulta me crea una tabla por cada producto incuso usando un `while`

```
 <?php
    require('./fpdf/fpdf.php');
    
    $pdf = new FPDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',20);    
    $textypos = 5;
    $pdf->setY(12);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    // Agregamos los datos de la empresa
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"LICORERIA LLANO LARGO CA");
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
    $pdf->setY(30);$pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"DE:");
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
    $pdf->setY(35);$pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Licoreria Llano Largo CA");
    $pdf->setY(40);$pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Sector Centro, Carrera 1, 
    Mantecal.");
    $pdf->setY(45);$pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"+58-2409940154");
    $pdf->setY(50);$pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"llanolargo@gmail.com");
    
    
    require './php/conexion.php';
    
    
    $datos = $conexion->query("select 
            ventas.*,  
            usuario.nombre,usuario.telefono,usuario.email
            from ventas 
            inner join usuario on ventas.id_usuario = usuario.id
            where ventas.id=".$_GET['id_venta'])or die($conexion->error);
    $datosUsuario = mysqli_fetch_row($datos);
    $datos2 = $conexion->query("select * from envios where id_venta=".$_GET['id_venta'])or die($conexion->error);
    $datosEnvio= mysqli_fetch_row($datos2);
    
    $datos3= $conexion->query("select productos_venta.*,    
                    productos.nombre as nombre_producto, productos.imagen 
                    from productos_venta inner join productos on productos_venta.id_producto = productos.id 
                    where id_venta =".$_GET['id_venta'])or die($conexion->error);
                    
    // **Agregamos los datos del cliente**
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
    $pdf->setY(30);$pdf->setX(75);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"PARA:");
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
    $pdf->setY(35);$pdf->setX(75);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"$datosUsuario[8]");
    $pdf->setY(40);$pdf->setX(75);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"$datosEnvio[1]");
    $pdf->setY(45);$pdf->setX(75);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"$datosUsuario[9]");
    $pdf->setY(50);$pdf->setX(75);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"$datosUsuario[10]");
    
    // **Agregamos los datos del cliente**
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
    $pdf->setY(30);$pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"FACTURA  #$_GET[id_venta]");
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
    $pdf->setY(35);$pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Fecha: $datosUsuario[10]");
    $pdf->setY(40);$pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->setY(45);$pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"");
    $pdf->setY(50);$pdf->setX(135);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"");
    
    /// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de productos
    $pdf->setY(60);$pdf->setX(135);
        $pdf->Ln();
    /////////////////////////////
    ////** Array de Cabecera**
    
    $header = array("Cod.", "Descripcion","Cant.","Precio","Total");
    //// Arrar de Productos
**Aca Uso el while para arrastar todos los datos**
    while($f = mysqli_fetch_array($datos3)){
    $products = array(array($f['id'], $f['nombre_producto'],$f['cantidad'],$f['precio'],0));
        // Column widths
        $w = array(20, 95, 20, 25, 25);
        // Header
        for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
            $pdf->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Ln();
        // Data
        $total = 0;
        foreach($products as $row)
        {
            $pdf->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],1);
            $pdf->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],1);
            $pdf->Cell($w[2],6,number_format($row[2]),'1',0,'R');
            $pdf->Cell($w[3],6,"$ ".number_format($row[3],2,".",","),'1',0,'R');
            $pdf->Cell($w[4],6,"$ ".number_format($row[3]*$row[2],2,".",","),'1',0,'R');
    
            $pdf->Ln();
            $total+=$row[3]*$row[2];
    
        }
    ** Apartir de aqui esta la tabla con los subtotales y totales**
    $yposdinamic = 60 + (count($products)*10);
    
    $pdf->setY($yposdinamic);
    $pdf->setX(235);
        $pdf->Ln();
    /////////////////////////////
    $header = array("", "");
    $data2 = array(
        array("Subtotal",$total),
        array("Descuento", 0),
        array("IVA", 0),
        array("Total", $total),
    );
        // Column widths
        $w2 = array(40, 40);
        // Header
    
        $pdf->Ln();
        // Data
        foreach($data2 as $row)
        {
    $pdf->setX(115);
            $pdf->Cell($w2[0],6,$row[0],1);
            $pdf->Cell($w2[1],6,"$ ".number_format($row[1], 2, ".",","),'1',0,'R');
    
            $pdf->Ln();
        }}
    /////////////////////////////
    
    $yposdinamic += (count($data2)*10);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
    
    $pdf->setY($yposdinamic);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"COMPROBANTES DE PAGO");
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
    
    $pdf->setY($yposdinamic+10);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Referencia: ");
    $pdf->setY($yposdinamic+20);
    $pdf->setX(10);
    $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Metodo de pago: , ");
    
    
    
    
    $pdf->output();
    ?>
```

[image: Acá se puede observar como me genera el pdf]

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que hacer el código? Yo veo que tú recorres cada producto en el bucle. Además tienes varios bucles uno dentro del otro y varias consultas SQL. ¿Por qué no consideras organizar mejor tu código haciendo una sola consulta con JOIN y una sola lectura dentro de un bucle, preferiblemente `while`, leyendo el recurso que te devuelva la consulta? Creo que el principal problema es el spaghetti que tienes en la consulta/lectura de datos.

Comment: y mejora tu pregunta.

Comment: Buenos días,  checa en esta pagina http://www.fpdf.org/ la sección de tutoriales : Tutorial 4: Columnas múltiples
Tutorial 5: Tablas  ahi encontraras algunos elementos que podrían serte útiles.  Tambien lo que comenta A.Cedano es importante, que en lugar que tengas varias consultas para recuperar tus datos, mejor utilices Join para en una sola pasada traer toda la informacion, y luego solo insertar en donde se requiere.  Saludos